# JavaScript forEach and 3 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, foreach, expand

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I have a problem. I'm building a randomizing page, where I use 3 arrays and 3 buttons. I want it to expand with the answer (button 1 - array no1, button 2 - array no2, etc) when the button is clicked. But the problem is that I only get the answer to the querySelectorAll for the first button anyway and only it expands.

For now i using only one array, but i can't figure out how to solve the problem of expanding buttons when they are clicked. How expand this button, which was clicked?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Shaggy6599/pen/gOBXjEG)

```js
console.clear();
const color = ["red", "green", "blue", "aqua", "black", "purple", "yellow"];
const fruits = [{
    type: "fruit",
    name: "orange",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/02/31/01/240_F_102310122_TyKkml1yRFle2IGtD2fAUrZLtixIGJqa.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "apple",
    img: "https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/10/32/02/240_F_310320273_I9rR1l7918MJoZ0GRHGIBgZl9F9ShEXq.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "banana",
    img: "https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/36/07/60/240_F_236076021_Lf2nHzSUcTxNGdG7hap6PjJNDwHT1VfC.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "mango",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/52/87/43/240_F_52874381_Ucxx67h9KLuxSXiNGcsmHfSjAuqRXqDr.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "kiwi",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/68/65/13/240_F_68651370_CVcQlAdJqvxtL8bIUm70UP1HwnFXOblQ.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "strawberries",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/84/36/81/240_F_84368117_irN0O3akL7ALdMe17ZtxH6nya1cHiG5H.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "grape",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/70/94/63/240_F_70946377_VJXdpJqld6XOsOTO6lt95ieZSxGO0faM.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "pear",
    img: ""
  }
];

let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".js-button");
let btn = document.querySelector(".js-button");
let isOpen = false;
let result = document.querySelector(".js-button-result");
let img = document.querySelector(".js-button-img");
let imgSrc = document.querySelector(".js-img");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!isOpen) {
    btn.classList.add("button--active");
    img.classList.add("button-img--active");
    result.classList.add("button-result--true");
    //draw.classList.add("draw--open")
    isOpen = true;
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);
    result.innerHTML = fruits[rand].name;
    imgSrc.src = fruits[rand].img;
  } else {
    btn.classList.remove("button--active");
    img.classList.remove("button-img--active");
    result.classList.remove("button-result--true");
    //draw.classList.remove("draw--open")
    isOpen = false;
  }
});

window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target !== btn /*&& e.target !== draw*/ ) {
    btn.classList.remove("button--active");
    img.classList.remove("button-img--active");
    result.classList.remove("button-result--true");
    //draw.classList.remove("draw--open")
    isOpen = false;
  }
});

btns.forEach((i) => {
  i.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let dataValue = event.target.getAttribute("data-value");

    /*if (!isOpen) {
    btn.classList.add("button--active");
    img.classList.add("button-img--active");
    result.classList.add("button-result--true");
    //draw.classList.add("draw--open")
    isOpen = true;
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);
    result.innerHTML = fruits[rand].name;
    imgSrc.src = fruits[rand].img;
    
  } else {
    btn.classList.remove("button--active");
    img.classList.remove("button-img--active");
    result.classList.remove("button-result--true");
    //draw.classList.remove("draw--open")
    isOpen = false;
  }
    */
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
}

.button {
  padding: 5% 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 20px;
  background-color: #dad7cd;
  user-select: none;
  transition: 100ms ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}

.button--active {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.button-result {
  display: none;
}

.button-result--true {
  display: block;
}

.button-img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.button-img--active {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.button:hover {
  outline: 2px solid #a3b18a;
  background-color: #a3b18a;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}

.button:active {
  outline-offset: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="js-button button button-1" data-value="1">
    Click!
    <div class="js-button-img button-img">
      <img class="js-img" alt="No image!" />
    </div>
    <div class="js-button-result button-result">
      Result
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="js-button button button-2" data-value="2">
    Click!
    <div class="js-button-img button-img">
      <img class="js-img" alt="No image!" />
    </div>
    <div class="js-button-result button-result">
      Result
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="js-button button button-3" data-value="3">
    Click!
    <div class="js-button-img button-img">
      <img class="js-img" alt="No image!" />
    </div>
    <div class="js-button-result button-result">
      Result
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: source code: https://codepen.io/Shaggy6599/pen/gOBXjEG

Comment: You have `let btn = document.querySelector(".js-button");` but multiple buttons with that classname. The event listener bound to `btn` will not service all buttons like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a delegated event listener, bound to the parent DIV element (`.wrapper`) and inspect the `event.target` to determine if the event originated on the button. From that point the event handler will function for all buttons rather than a single button that might be identified using `querySelector`

You can simplify some of the above code by using the `toggle` method for the classList operations rather than the `isOpen` logic block.

The following does, I think, what you were trying to do(?) but uses a single listener. Perhaps it will help.

```js
const color = [
  "red", "green", "blue", "aqua", "black", "purple", "yellow"
];
const fruits = [{
    type: "fruit",
    name: "orange",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/02/31/01/240_F_102310122_TyKkml1yRFle2IGtD2fAUrZLtixIGJqa.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "apple",
    img: "https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/10/32/02/240_F_310320273_I9rR1l7918MJoZ0GRHGIBgZl9F9ShEXq.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "banana",
    img: "https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/36/07/60/240_F_236076021_Lf2nHzSUcTxNGdG7hap6PjJNDwHT1VfC.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "mango",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/52/87/43/240_F_52874381_Ucxx67h9KLuxSXiNGcsmHfSjAuqRXqDr.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "kiwi",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/68/65/13/240_F_68651370_CVcQlAdJqvxtL8bIUm70UP1HwnFXOblQ.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "strawberries",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/84/36/81/240_F_84368117_irN0O3akL7ALdMe17ZtxH6nya1cHiG5H.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "fruit",
    name: "grape",
    img: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/70/94/63/240_F_70946377_VJXdpJqld6XOsOTO6lt95ieZSxGO0faM.jpg"
  }
];



const d = document;

// class names used
const css = {
  'bttn': 'js-button',
  'active': 'button--active',
  'bttnresult': 'js-button-result',
  'bttnrestrue': 'button-result--true',
  'img': 'button-img--active'
};

// parent node to bind delegated listener to
const wrapper = d.querySelector('div.wrapper');

// create a pseudo random number between low & high bounds
const mt_rand = (a, b) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);

// use the random number to return a random item from an input array
const getarray = (src) => src[mt_rand(0, src.length - 1)];


let is_open = false; // global boolean to indicate panel open status
let img_src; // store reference to selected fruit image for use when closing panel


wrapper.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLDivElement && e.target.classList.contains(css.bttn) && e.target.parentNode == wrapper) {
    // find the dataset attribute(s)
    let value = Number( e.target.dataset.value );
    // find the IMG element
    let img = e.target.querySelector('img');
    // find the div that will display the fruit name
    let result = e.target.querySelector(`.${css.bttnresult}`);
    // select a random fruit ( or other type of "thing" )
    let fruit = getarray(fruits);

    // toggle the class for current button/panel and associated child elements
    e.target.classList.toggle(css.active);

    result.classList.toggle(css.bttnrestrue);
    result.textContent = !is_open ? fruit.name : '';

    img.parentNode.classList.toggle(css.img);
    img.src = !is_open ? fruit.img : img_src;
    img.alt = !is_open ? fruit.name : 'No image!';

    console.info('Panel:%d is open:%s', value, !is_open)

    // toggle the global boolean variable to indicate open status
    is_open = !is_open;
    img_src = fruit.img;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
}

.button {
  padding: 5% 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 20px;
  background-color: #dad7cd;
  user-select: none;
  transition: 100ms ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button--active {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.button-result {
  display: none;
}

.button-result--true {
  display: block;
}

.button-img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.button-img--active {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
}

.button:hover {
  outline: 2px solid #a3b18a;
  background-color: #a3b18a;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}

.button:active {
  outline-offset: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="js-button button button-1" data-value="1">
    Click!
    <div class="js-button-img button-img">
      <img class="js-img" alt="No image!" />
    </div>
    <div class="js-button-result button-result"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="js-button button button-2" data-value="2">
    Click!
    <div class="js-button-img button-img">
      <img class="js-img" alt="No image!" />
    </div>
    <div class="js-button-result button-result"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="js-button button button-3" data-value="3">
    Click!
    <div class="js-button-img button-img">
      <img class="js-img" alt="No image!" />
    </div>
    <div class="js-button-result button-result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hope it helped! Good luck with further coding adventures

Answer (score 0):

```
btns.forEach((i) => {
  i.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let dataValue = event.target.getAttribute("data-value");

    /*if (!isOpen) {
    //btn.classList.add("button--active"); 
    i.classList.add("button--active"); 
    img.classList.add("button-img--active");
    result.classList.add("button-result--true");
    //draw.classList.add("draw--open")
    isOpen = true;
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);
    result.innerHTML = fruits[rand].name;
    imgSrc.src = fruits[rand].img;
    
  } else {
    // btn.classList.remove("button--active");
    i.classList.remove("button--active");
    img.classList.remove("button-img--active");
    result.classList.remove("button-result--true");
    //draw.classList.remove("draw--open")
    isOpen = false;
  }
    */
  });
});
```

in your btns.forEach body, you use `btn.classList.add("button--active");` , the btn is not current element, it will not change with the iterator. you can use `i` to replace `btn`